# Tesseract Not Found error occuring in IDLE but not in Terminal

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am working on some OCR and chose to use tesseract as the library. So, I installed it using the pip command in the terminal and when I tested the library with a sample image it seems to be working fine(in the terminal). I have no idea why it wouldn't work in IDLE and python versions of the idle and terminal are the same down to the exact detail. Can someone help me with this?

thanks!

P.S: the text output is something I just scribbled down and isn't something that was wrong.

[image: this is the code on IDLE][image: code on terminal]

Comment: Try to provide exact information what you do in terminal and how you run tesseract in IDLE.